# Chamar a data que tabela foi criada

Tags: mysql

Estava vendo este [tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated) onde ele mostra a última vez que a tabela foi atualizada. Só que eu quero saber quando a tabela foi criada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quase igual, só usa `CREATE_TIME` ao invés de `UPDATE_TIME`

```
SELECT CREATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'
```

Referência na [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html)